# Printing output data (data-frames / matrices) along with plots in .pdf format in R

Tags: r

I would like to print my result of R codes viz. a few data frames (approx 4-5) and a few plots (4 plots) in a pdf file i.e. I want to export all the output in a pdf file using some set of codes (that I would like to run at the end) or in a separate file i.e. outside of mother/core/main codes (like by using `rmarkdown::render("analysis.R", "pdf_document")`. Also, I would like to achieve: -

a. I want to print only the output (and not the coding). For this, some commands like `#+echo=FALSE` were found useful which I am using/placing at the beginning of my mother code file and running the below ones (in an external file): -

`library(rmarkdown)
render("Analysis.R", output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = "Aalysis_Output",quiet = TRUE)`

b. But my tables are not formatted, they are getting split into many tables (being they are a little wide and so the rownames are getting replicated in each table too and each table just having one column - I have three columns in total - so I am getting 3 tables).

c. Moreover, I am getting "##" in each line/row of output which I want to remove.

Also note that currently, I don't want to use R Markdown or KnitR... (as I don't want a .Rmd file etc. for my R codes). Is there any way to do the same easily - like what we use to do in C programming - we open a text file and start writing our results/output of C using fprinft etc.)

Below are all my datasets (R data-frames) and plots (I used ggplot in R to create plots) which I want to get printed in a well-formatted pdf file.

```
## Printing all the results & plots ##

print(base_result, right = T)   # Base Results

print(DSA_AP, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs P
Torn_AP                         # Tornado for Drug A vs P

print(DSA_AQ, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs Q
Torn_AQ                         # Tornado for Drug A vs Q

print(DSA_AR, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs R
Torn_AR                         # Tornado for Drug A vs R

print(DSA_AS, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs S
Torn_AS                         # Tornado for Drug A vs S
```

I tried the following codes to get the result: -

```
Set-1 Codes: Issue it’s not printing the tables/data-frames (but plotting all the plots only).

    pdf("MyOutput_12.pdf", paper = "A4")

    print(base_result, right = T)   # Base Results 
    # Issue: It is only coming as a print in the console and similarly for below tables.

    print(DSA_AP, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs P
    Torn_AP                         # Tornado for Drug A vs P

    print(DSA_AQ, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs Q
    Torn_AQ                         # Tornado for Drug A vs Q

    print(DSA_AR, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs R
    Torn_AR                         # Tornado for Drug A vs R

    print(DSA_AS, right = T)        # DSA for Drug A vs S
    Torn_AS                         # Tornado for Drug A vs S

    dev.off()

Set-2 Codes: Now, it’s printing the tables but it is printing one over the previous table or plot i.e. overwriting (below are the codes for printing three datasets and two plots).

    library(gridExtra)

    pdf("MyOutput_14.pdf", paper = "A4")

    grid.table(base_result)

    grid.table(DSA_AP)              # DSA for Drug A vs P
    Torn_AP                         # Tornado for Drug A vs P


    grid.table(DSA_AQ)              # DSA for Drug A vs Q
    Torn_AQ                         # Tornado for Drug A vs Q

    dev.off()

Moreover, in the set-2 the tables are some big and getting truncated i.e. the right part of each table is missing (getting cut in pdf file) -- need to adjust width etc. of tables in the pdf file print.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found codes serving the purpose 'a' and 'c' and for 'b' I now decreased the column headings and row names of my data frames (output-tables) to save space/page and now I am getting the required output. I used the following codes: -

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 7, fig.height = 5, fig.align = 'left', dpi = 96, echo = F, comment = "", message = F, warning = F)

# For PDF Output
rmarkdown::render("Model_3.3.R", output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = "Output_3.3_01.pdf")

# For HTML Output
rmarkdown::render("Model_3.3.R", output_format = "html_document", output_file = "Output_3.3_01.html")
```

Note: These codes are required to run outside the mother codes i.e. in a separate file or in R / RStudio console.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way, if you are using Rstudio, is to write your script, then hit control + shift + K. This automatically creates a report, and you can choose PDF output if you want. Note: under the hood this is still using RMarkdown - but you do not have to write an RMD file yourself, so maybe this is okay?

Comment: Hi Dash, thanks for the reply. Good to know this. But I need (a) only the output and currently, it's printing the codes too - however, I know a way to overcome from it using `rmarkdown::render("analysis.R", "pdf_document")` and #+ Echo= False, in the code file; (b) But the main concern is the tables are not coming formatted (I have some big tables), and cloumns are getting split in 3 tables..

Comment: For that you might try my `huxtable` package or the `kable` package. They both provide for pretty-printing of data frames.